# What is the meaning of h(r) in this protocol?

Tags: hash, public-key, notation

Could somebody tell me what the meaning is of $h(r)$ in the protocol below?

‎‎$A‎\leftarrow‎{B}\quad:{h(r)‎‎}{,B}{,P{_A(r,B)}}‎
\\A‎\rightarrow‎{B}\quad:r$

Comment: $h$ is a hash function. $\;$

Answer (score 1):

As [Ricky Demer already mentioned](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25012/what-is-the-meaning-of-hr-in-this-protocol#comment57025_25012), $h$ is a hash function.

In the realms of cryptography, it mostly points to a secure hash function. But in the end, it doesn’t matter if it’s a secure hash or not… $h$ is standard notation for “hash”.